# What type of transformer is this? No other information on it. Thanks, just a newbie

Tags: transformer

[image]

This is in what we call a hole finder use in drilling stone.

Comment: Did you intend to write anything in the body of the question other than "This is in what we call a hole finder use in drilling stone." Is this a joke or a real question?

Comment: is it just those 6 wires connecting to the transformer?

Comment: Looks like a bobbin-wound, laminated-steel, E-I core transformer, around 3 inches on a side, with two center-tapped windings; unclear from the photo whether or not there is a primary winding on the back -- which might be for high voltage AC mains power supply. Is there any label on back, "Hi-pot test OK" would confirm it's rated for AC mains, otherwise it might be intended for low-voltage audio. If you can edit your question to provide more context, you might get better responses.

Answer (score 3):

According to the label, it's a centre-tapped 24 V to centre-tapped 24 V isolating transformer.

Comment: Chances are also excellent that it's rated at 18VA and intended for 12:12 VAC at 50 or 60Hz.

Comment: What are the chances that there is another winding that is not shown?

Comment: Fairly good I would say, often transformers have the primary terminated on the opposite side of the core to the secondary